# How to prove $(\forall x)(A\to B)\to(\exists x)A\to(\exists x)B$

Tags: predicate-logic

I am stuck on this one, I know I have to use Ax3 which is $$(\forall x)(A\to B)\to(\exists x)A\to(\exists x)B$$ and convert the existential quantifier to universal, but I have problem making it to become just as Ax3

The original was just like the following:

Show that |- $(\forall x)(A\to B)\to(\exists x)A\to(\exists x)B$

Hint: Use the definition of existential quantifier to eliminate ∃

Comment: You're missing parentheses, the formula is ill-formed. What rules and axioms do you have available?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I believe it's the axoim quoted in the question. And I don't believe it's enough.

Comment: the parentheses are exactly like the one given in the question

Comment: @ColmBhandal the axoim is just the one i guess i might make use of

Comment: If you are working with an [Hilbert-style proof system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_system#Logical_axioms) like Enderton's one, you need some basic meta-theorems, like **Deduction Th** and **Generalization Th** as well as $\vdash ( ∃ xβ →α) ↔ ∀x(β → α)$, where $x$ does not occur free in $α$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use Ax3 to prove that property. I don't know what rules you're allowed to use, but I would do the following: Assume that $\forall x (A \implies B)$ and $\exists x A$. Then eliminate the existential to get some particular $A$. Then apply $\forall x (A \implies B)$ to get a particular $B$. Then use this $B$ as the witness to the final existential.

Comment: Ohh ok, got it! thank you!